# How to teach to draw graphs of quadratic equations without knowing calculus?

Tags: teaching

In the country I'm living we learn how to draw the graph of quadratic equations such as $y=x^2$ or $y=x^2+5x+3$ before knowing calculus (in fact we don't even learn calculus until we begin the undergraduate studies) using the fact they are parabolas.

For me this is just a memorization. Are there some standard recognized methods to show students quadratic equations are parabolas?

Comment: Frankly, "the graph of a quadratic equation" is the definition of a parabola.  The old "locus of points" and "intersection of a cone with a plane" definitions are hopelessly old-fashioned.

Comment: Hopelessly oldfashioned? What's the world coming to? Parabolic mirrors, Lithotripsy, headlights, Kepler's laws. Archimedes, Apollonius, Pascal, Dandelin,  Poncelet. Oh my God . . .

Comment: How, in your context, is "parabola" defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the definition of a parabola as a [locus of points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Definition_of_a_parabola_as_locus_of_points):

> A parabola is a set of points, such that for any point $P$ of the set the distance $|PF|$ to a fixed point $F$, the focus, is equal to the distance $|Pl|$ to a fixed line $l$, the directrix: $\{P\mid|PF|=|Pl|\}$

Then locate the parabola in a rectangular coordinate system.  Start with the simplest case of a parabola with its focus $F$ at coordinates $(0,f)$ (with $f>0$) and its directrix at $y=-f$.  For a point $P$ (with coordinates $(x,y)$) on the parabola, we get from $|PF|^2=|Pl|^2$ the equation $x^2+(y-f)^2=(y+f)^2$.  This results in the quadratic equation $y=\frac{1}{4f}x^2$.

Give more complicated examples until you get to the [general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#General_case).

Comment: What I presented was how to show that parabolas are quadratic equations, but I think that that should be enough to see that quadratic equations are parabolas.

Comment: +1 for starting with a reasonable definition of "parabola". FYI, this is how [my high school text](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000XPXF1S) dealt with equations for circles, ellipses, parabolas, and hyperbolas, and how nearly every (if not absolutely every) precalculus, college algebra, and the older analytic geometry texts I've seen in 40+ years did this, which has me wondering whether the wording of the original question accurately conveys what user26832 wanted to know.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the most celebrated applications of completing the square.  $$y=ax^2+bx+c \Longrightarrow y=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$  Since a square (in your non-complex context) must be nonnegative, and will have a minimum when it is zero, the vertex of the parabola will be at $$(x,y)=(-b/2a,c-b^2/4a)$$  If this equation doesn't look like the stretched parabola $ax^2$ shifted by this vertex, what would?

Also, you can find the places it hits the $x$-axis by solving for $y=0$ using the quadratic formula or factoring.  The $y$-intercept would be $c$, of course.  Hopefully with these three pieces of information you could plot as much as you want.

By the way, this isn't really a matheducators.SX type answer, but I hope it leads you to thinking about the many problems typically assaulted with calculus that may not need it, proving that [dogs don't need calculus](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/074683410x475074).

Comment: The problem is how do you know this is a parabola. Once we know it's a parabola is easy to plot the graph.

Comment: How do we know $ax^2$ is a parabola?  That is a little deeper - do you mean you want to prove that it is the locus of points such that ... ?  Looks like someone else has covered that case.  But I find that this is more sophisticated than students could handle at that point; the "locus" definition is not so easy.

Comment: Use the idea of "graph transformations" -- when you replace x with (x-a) you shift the graph a units to the right, when you add or subtract outside the squaring you shift the graph up or down, and multiplying by a constant scales vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is a highly visual problem. I'd agree with Mr. Noche in that the best way to approach this is from a geometry perspective. In addition. I'd use something like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), to show students how the graph of a line changes when we "multiply by x" (how, for example, the equation $y=ax^{2}+b$ seems to "open and bend" as a gets progressively closer to 0 and the equation gets closer to $y=b.$

Like Mr. Noche suggests, start slowly, adding complications as students get more comfortable the equation's structure. Here's how I would approach this thing:

- Refresh students on linear variation.
- Numerically compare linear variation to quadratic variation.
- Have them plot $y=x$ (by hand or in Desmos)
- Have them plot $y=x^{2}.$ Discuss similarities and
  differences.
- Ask something like: "What do you think will happen if I
  add some number $b$ to this equation?" After some discussion, show
  them what happens.
- Ask them something like "What do you think will happen if I make this number $b$ bigger/smaller?"
- Ask them something like: "What would happen if I
  multiply this $x^{2}$ by some number $a$?
- Build progressively, until students are playing around with the general quadratic.